# What is the correct syntax for WinSCP Session.ScanFingerprint()?

Tags: .net, ssh, scp, winscp, winscp-net

I need to use the WinSCP API to programmatically retrieve fingerprints from remote protocol devices on our network. Right now this is done tediously by opening a Windows UI WinSCP session and transcribing the fingerprints from the popup window displayed when a fingerprint is about to be cached.

I see in documentation where I can use `Session.ScanFingerprin`t for this, but it appears to be returning an ASCII string:

```
ssh-rsa 1040 Rrt2/hXxs+i3Ugz1YeZUXIk/gjliFNyyA9WHBYCu0m8=
```

instead of the hex-encoded value I was expecting:

```
ssh-rsa 1040 ef:aa:a1:30:79:12:c7:f8:02:36:d0:ac:71:6b:5b:24
```

`ScanFingerprint` requires an `algorithm` parameter, which I am supplying as the string `"SHA-256"`; I haven't been able to find any examples to say whether or not this is correct.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Scp,
    HostName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", // IP address
    UserName = "root",
    Password = "root",

    //SshHostKeyFingerprint = fingerprint
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey=true
};
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("AuthGSSAPI", "1");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Cipher", "aes,blowfish,3des,chacha20,WARN,arcfour,des");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("KEX", "ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,dh-group1-sha1,rsa,WARN");
Session session;
using (session = new Session())
{
    //session.DisableVersionCheck = true;
    try
    {
        Log("Opening session");
        string fingerprint = null;
        fingerprint = session.ScanFingerprint(sessionOptions,"SHA-256");
        string t = fingerprint;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("WinSCP: " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

Am I supplying the wrong algorithm parameter, or do I need to reinterpret the fingerprint string I am retrieving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Base64-encoded SHA-256 fingerprint, returned for `algorithm = "SHA-256"`:

```
ssh-rsa 1040 Rrt2/hXxs+i3Ugz1YeZUXIk/gjliFNyyA9WHBYCu0m8=
```

This is hex-encoded MD5 fingerprint, returned for `algorithm = "MD5"`:

```
ssh-rsa 1040 ef:aa:a1:30:79:12:c7:f8:02:36:d0:ac:71:6b:5b:24
```

See [documentation for `algorithm` argument of `Session.ScanFingerprint`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_scanfingerprint#algorithm).

You should use SHA-256, if possible, as MD5 is not considered secure anymore.

WinSCP understands both (both can be used for `SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint`, for `-hostkey` switch in WinSCP scripting or anywhere else).

---

*Also note that there's no need to set `UserName`, `Password`, `GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey` (superseded by `SshHostKeyPolicy`), `AuthGSSAPI` or `Cipher` for `Session.ScanFingerprint` call.*